# gevent 'StreamServer' object has no attribute 'pre_start'?

Tags: python, gevent

i install python and gevent on my mac, but when i try to use

```
s = StreamServer(xx,xx)
s.pre_start()
```

it gets error:'StreamServer' object has no attribute 'pre_start'?

the version information of python and gevent:
    Python 2.7.5 Gevent 1.0.1

Answer (score 1):

pre_start method has been rename to init_socket
see in: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/cec56a6a3d8ba8968f6ff5ef969a5775e4f10e8b/changelog.rst#release-10b1-jan-10-2012

Answer (score 0):

[In the source code for server.py](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/blob/master/gevent/server.py), where StreamServer is implemented, you can see that it inherits from BaseServer.

BaseServer itself is implemented in [baseserver.py](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/blob/master/gevent/baseserver.py)

A quick look at these two files reveals that neither StreamServer nor BaseServer has an attribute `pre_start`, that is why you get an error when you try to call `.pre_start()` on a variable of type `StreamServer`.

I do not know what it is you're trying to accomplish, but you're gonna have to do it another way.